# Is there any standard way for user apps to access coprocessor on ARM Linux?

Tags: linux, arm

I wonder if there is an already implemented (common - standard) "driver/kernel module/sysfs entry" way to access ARM's coprocessor through user space. If not (to my knowledge), why it is not available? Is there anything blocking it? Isn't it feasible?

For example; I want to get the contents of [Main ID Register - MIDR](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0388h/BABCBFDF.html), I would like to be able to do this from user space by writing to / reading from a sysfs entry.

Comment: /proc/cpuinfo contains all the information that you could glean specifically from the MIDR, albeit optimized for human consumption.

What purpose do you intend to use this value for?

Comment: to access any coprocessor register I want. MIDR was just an example. What happens if you would like to see if Branch Predictor is enabled? (http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0388h/BABDHHGI.html)

Comment: The MIDR is a register that will provide a userspace application with no useful information (whereas hwcaps might).

And if your branch predictor is not enabled, then your kernel is fundamentally broken.

(Putting the rest in an answer as my comment got too long :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is generally a bad idea to expose that level of intricate hardware connection to application software - it breaks portability and can affect security and stability (which is why they are not accessible from unprivileged mode to begin with). Such things are usually better hidden behind some layers of software abstractions. But nothing prevents you from writing kernel drivers that expose such interfaces where a real reason exists.

If your question is from a pure perspective of curiosity, then I would recommend building your own kernel and either use something like KGDB to investigate during startup or simply insert printk statements in strategic locations to see what certain values are at given points.

Comment: Access can be controlled via sysfs permissions. Assume you want to read some HW performance counter, you need to write a module just for that. If that was available to your user space app, wouldn't be more useful to use them for various performance benchmarks? Of course you can talk about a library to do so, but even that library needs a module and that needs to be compiled with the right version of Linux...

Comment: If you want to use the hw performance counters under Linux, then the best way of doing that would be to use the perf framework - not exposing hw counters to user-space which has no way of telling when it's being context-switched out or preventing other processes from overwriting its performance counter configurations.

That said, specifically the performance counters have a configuration option that can be set to permit configuration by unprivileged software. But that would make (marginal) sense only in an operating system that did not expose the counters any other way.

Comment: (some other argument) You can access all the physical memory through /dev/mem, that's the same way of access I'm talking about.