# ARM Ubuntu: how way to run code in privileged mode?

Tags: ubuntu, arm, elevated-privileges

I have an ARM Samsung Chromebook running Ubuntu (chrUbuntu 12.04).

What is the easiest way to run some code in ARM 'privileged' state?  I'm not looking for sudo, I'm looking for ARM processor mode of Supervisor, IRQ, FIQ, etc.  Someplace I can probe/modify the coprocessor registers.

It's easy to get to priv mode: just do an SVC call.  The question is, what is the easiest way to get some of my own code plugged into the OS so it gets called on a certain SVC call?

I'm not much of a Linux hacker.  Mostly I'm looking for general pointers on the easiest general direction (rebuild the kernel? grab some driver source and hook in a modified driver?  some easy command line option to run something priv?), then I'll go from there.

---

In case my above approach makes no sense and there is an easier way, my overall goal is:

- write some low level assembly routines
- see how they perform with various hardware configurations of the Cortex-A15 core

Thanks in advance,

Paul

Comment: The easiest way is to forget about the chrome book entirely and run it in an emulator.

Comment: I'm trying to optimize code specifically for the Cortex-A15 processor.  An emulator will not help, as it will be *way* too slow, and will not correctly represent Cortex-A15 behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to access coprocessors registers in case they are not allowed from user land is running some initialization code in kernel boot up sequence like board-init or write a kernel module to do what you want. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3250835/1163019). Also if interested, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12314072/1163019).

Comment: Very helpful. I'll pursue the kernel module approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For the second version of your question:
Sound to me like you want the perf tools, rather than trying to implement your own performance measurements: https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial

The other way would be through implementing a loadable kernel module. If you create a module, as a driver or as something accessed through /proc or /sys, that module will execute in Supervisor mode.

Comment: Two answers: 
1) General perf tools would be fine, but getting at some of the raw performance counters in A15 would be better.  I don't need portability. 

2) I would also like to be able to manipulate some of the hardware parameters (slower L2 cache, adjust hardware prefetch, etc.).  For this I need kernel mode.  
  
Because of this, I'm pursuing the kernel module (likely just a block device driver).  

My issue now: I'm running ChrUbuntu, which just grabs the original ChromeOS kernel.  I don't have /lib/modules/build.  Still exploring options.

Comment: 1) What benefit are you expecting from writing this code yourself rather than by accessing the very same counters through perf?

2) This type of modification is usually easier to do once, at boot time (preferably before caches/MMU have been enabled).

Have a look at http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-guide#TOC-Get-the-Source for info about getting access to the kernel sources.

Comment: Putting the perf counters in user mode: no advantage.  I may use perf for that.  For the rest (modifying L2 latency, prefetch configuration, write-streaming, etc) my goal is to test the code I'm writing in different configurations.  I'm working now to build my own kernel for the chromebook from source.  Once I do that, I should be good to go.  Thanks for the pointers!